# Angular application: dynamically lazy load an external Angular component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

There are a lot of questions, threads, documentations about Angular lazy loading but none of them answer the question I have.

Say you have an Angular application on one side and in another project an Angular component (available through app, lib or what compilation is required ? this is part of the quesion).

Now I want my application to lazy load the component. The application and the component do not know each other. The only thing that the application knows is the URL path to js file implementing the component.

NB:

- the component is pure Angular, it is not adapated somehow as a CustomElement.
- the component might have its own injector hierarchy, thus service that the Application is not aware

What I would like to know :

- Is it possible for an Angular application to lazy load a component (through `import()` and any other steps) that has not been built with it?
- If it is possible, how ?

To avoid simplistic answers, what I already know :

- You can lazy load internal a internal feature module with the router, this is well documented https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
- You can lazy load an internal standalone component with the router, it is well documentated https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#routing-and-lazy-loading
- You may be able to load an internal component outside the router mechanism (say from inside a component method), with the same result. Angular does not provide direct way to do it but this might be possible https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18093

I tried to POC lazy loading a component from a library, and complete angular application in another angular application, without success.